# Wrapping Flutter IndexedStack in a Column breaks it

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an IndexedStack widget with tabs on the bottom as the home page of my app and I would like to add a "forehead" on my app. So naturally, I tried to wrap that IndexedStack in a Column to add my widget on top of it, but the simple fact of wrapping the IndexedStack in the column broke it and turned it into a blank space.

Any idea how I can circumvent this ?

Thanks in advance !

Code:

```
Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: [
              IndexedStack(
                index: viewModel.currentTabIndex,
                children: <Widget>[
                  if (viewModel.canScreen1) const Screen1(),
                  if (viewModel.canScreen2) const Screen2(),
                  DashboardScreen()
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar:
              viewModel.canScreen1 || viewModel.canScreen2
                  ? const BaseNavigationViewBottomBar()
                  : null,
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wrap your `IndexedStack` with `Expanded` widget like below

```
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
  child: IndexedStack(
                index: viewModel.currentTabIndex,
                children: <Widget>[
                  if (viewModel.canScreen1) const Screen1(),
                  if (viewModel.canScreen2) const Screen2(),
                  DashboardScreen()
                ],
              ),
       )
  ],
)
```